# Download a file that is written to the Response stream in ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stream, response

The objective:
 - Server side: Write a file to the response stream after verifying credentials. In other words, no public access to the file.
 - Client side: Download this file by from http://xyz.com?credentials=abc

So far, the ASPX page does the following:

- Verify credentials
- this.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
- this.Response.BinaryWrite(binaryReader.ReadBytes(1024));

What is the best way to download this file data from a WinForms app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(url, filename);
```

(Either start this not in the UI thread, or use the async version. You don't want your UI thread to block while downloading.)

Comment: I assume the files does not have to be publically accessible over HTTP in this case since the URL will contain credentials and the file will be written to the response stream using server-side code?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: You can set the credentials for the web client to use. The file certainly doesn't have to be available on an SMB share or anything like that.